# Ncurses: comparing input and a chosen word from the textfile

Tags: c, ncurses

I'd like to make the "Falling words" typing game (you type the word before it lands on the bottom of console) but I'm stuck because I don't know if my declaration might even work.

For now this function:

- opens the textfile with list of words
- chooses random word from the file (I haven't made that, found on the net).
- prints it with animation of falling (number of column is also random)

The problem is: I have no clue how to compare variable 'input' with current falling word. My tries with scanw function have failed so far and I'm not sure if fgets would be better.

EDIT: I tried with strcmp and if function but it doesn't really help - my will is to make the word falling and in the same time I can write this word. If both strings are same, it should print "SAME", but it doesn't work and I don't know why...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int col = 0;
int row = 0;
extern WINDOW *stdscr;

int ruch()
{
FILE *fp = NULL;
char words[67];
char input[67];
int i = 0 , ran = 0;

while(1)
{
int ch = 0;
int each = 0;

int x = rand()%70;

//opening file
if ( ( fp = fopen("list.txt" , "r")) == NULL) {
    perror ( "could not open file");
    exit ( 1);
}

for( i = 0; fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp) ; i++);//loop to count words in file
ran = rand() % i;//random word
rewind(fp);
for(i = 0 ; i < ran ; i++)//loop to get random word
    fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp);
fclose(fp);
if ( words[strlen(words)-1] == '\n')
    words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';// remove newline

//animation
for( i=0;i<22;i++)
{
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
    clear();
    mvprintw(1+i ,x , words );
    refresh();
    usleep(500000);
    ch = getch();//get a character
    if ( ch != ERR) {
        input[each] = ch;//add character to input
        each++;
        input[each] = '\0';//terminate input
        mvprintw(1, 1, input);
        if(strcmp(input,words) == 0) {
            //mvprintw(5, 1, "SAME\n");
            //return 1;
            break;

        }

        else {
            if ( strlen ( input) >= strlen ( words)) {//correct number of characters input but do not match
                clear();
                mvprintw(6, 1, "YOU TYPO'D, GAME OVER");
                return 2;
            }
        }
        continue;
    }
    //usleep(100);
    continue;
    mvprintw(6, 1, "GAME OVER");

}
continue;
 }

}

int main()
{
initscr();
srand(time(NULL));
nodelay ( stdscr, TRUE);//so getch does not wait for a character
raw();
ruch();
getch();
usleep(3000000);
endwin();
return 0;
}
```

Please keep in mind I'm kind of beginner in C :) Would love to get some help.

Regards.

Comment: You already have `strcmp` there; so what does really go wrong when comparing the two strings?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the Help Center, particularly [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is too broad: we answer questions about specific programming problems, but your question is more about _designing_ a program.

Comment: Note that you're doing some really odd things when reading the words from the file, including the empty-ish loop over the contents and then rewinding; why?

Comment: @DarkDust There is actual code, and in bold in the question is the apparent problem. The question is just unclear by itself, but does not appear to be about designing a program.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get how to add full code in the brackets. @Evert, this part you talk about was taken from the other forUm because I couldn't make my choose function to work well...

Comment: @Evert: I didn't even bother to look at the Pastebin (when people are using it, that usually means it's too large to be posted here). Have inlined it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "was taken from the other form because I couldn't make my choose function to work well". But since this (presumably) about reading the word list, that's not the problem at hand. You will, however, need to explain the actual problem better (edit your question for that, instead of using comments).

Comment: typo: forum, not form
okay, I will

Comment: Also please note that `real-time` has a very specific meaning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing

Comment: Edited everything, I wish I had made it more clear now.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I changed my code, hope I made that correctly. Still, it does nothing after the animation (looks like doesn't get any input).

Comment: As I understood, you wanted to change fgets to scanw in "//choosing random word from the file" and stay with fgets in "//problem", yes? Unfortunately, now the code just gets the written characters and instantly prints them.

Could you also answer if construction strcmp(input,words) is even correct?

Comment: Okay, I changed the code like you said but I don't understand how to remove the newline?
And still have no idea how to make that scanw and strcmp work together...

Comment: Okay then, did change again, there's no newline.
Now what about that if(strcmp) if that's correct? It doesn't work for me...

Comment: haha he's my friend, he's making same project with other methods but he has other problem as I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int col = 0;
int row = 0;
extern WINDOW *stdscr;

int ruch()
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char words[67];
    char input[67];
    int i = 0 , ran = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    int each = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x = rand()%70;

    //opening file
    if ( ( fp = fopen("list.txt" , "r")) == NULL) {
        perror ( "could not open file");
        exit ( 1);
    }

    //choosing random word from the file
    for(; fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp) ; i++);//loop to count words in file
    ran = rand() % i;//random word
    rewind(fp);
    for(i = 0 ; i < ran ; i++)//loop to get random word
        fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp);
    fclose(fp);
    if ( words[strlen(words)-1] == '\n')
        words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';// remove newline

    //animation
    for( i=0;i<22;i++)
    {
        getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
        clear();
        mvprintw(1+i ,x , words );
        refresh();
        usleep(500000);
        ch = getch();//get a character
        if ( ch != ERR) {
            input[each] = ch;//add character to input
            each++;
            input[each] = '\0';//terminate input
            mvprintw(1, 1, input);
            if(strcmp(input,words) == 0) {
                mvprintw(5, 1, "SAME\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                if ( strlen ( input) >= strlen ( words)) {//correct number of characters input but do not match
                    mvprintw(6, 1, "NOT SAME");
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        }
        usleep(100);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    initscr();
    nodelay ( stdscr, TRUE);//so getch does not wait for a character
    raw();
    ruch();
    getch();
    usleep(3000000);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

This has the opening of the file before the while loop. Typing a slash, '/', ends the loop.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int col = 0;
int row = 0;
extern WINDOW *stdscr;

int ruch()
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char words[67];
    char input[67];
    char score[80] = {"Score\n"};
    int i = 0 , ran = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    int each = 0;
    int points = 0;
    int filewords = 0;
    int x = 0;

    //opening file
    if ( ( fp = fopen("list.txt" , "r")) == NULL) {
        perror ( "could not open file");
        exit ( 1);
    }
    for( filewords = 0; fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp) ; filewords++);//loop to count words in file

    while ( 1) {
        //choosing random word from the file
        ran = rand() % filewords;//random word
        rewind(fp);
        for(i = 0 ; i < ran ; i++)//loop to get random word
            fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp);
        if ( words[strlen(words)-1] == '\n')
            words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';// remove newline

        x = rand()%(col - strlen(words));

        clear();
        mvprintw(0, (col - strlen ( score))/2, score);
        mvprintw(1, (col - strlen ( score))/2, "To end, type a '/'.  Get ready...");
        refresh();
        usleep(2000000);

        //animation
        for( i=0;i<row-1;i++)
        {
            clear();
            mvprintw(0, (col - strlen ( score))/2, score);
            mvprintw(1+i ,x , words );
            refresh();
            usleep(400000);
            ch = getch();//get a character
            if ( ch != ERR) {
                if ( ch == '/') {
                    fclose(fp);//close the file
                    return 0;
                }
                input[each] = ch;//add character to input
                each++;
                input[each] = '\0';//terminate input
                mvprintw(1, 1, input);
                if(strcmp(input,words) == 0) {
                    points += strlen ( words) + ( row - i);
                    sprintf ( score, "Score %d correct\n", points);
                    each = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    if ( strlen ( input) >= strlen ( words)) {//correct number of characters input but do not match
                        points -= (int)(strlen ( words));
                        sprintf ( score, "Score %d typo %s %s\n", points, words, input);
                        each = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ( i == row - 1) {
            points -= row;
            sprintf ( score, "Score %d timeout\n", points);
        }
        each = 0;
        getch();
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    initscr();
    nodelay ( stdscr, TRUE);//so getch does not wait for a character
    raw();
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
    ruch();
    getch();
    usleep(30000);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, thank you so much for the fix! Now the last thing to improve is to make it looped. I edited the original code; was thinking about the while(1) loop with "//choosing random word" and "for" loop inside and using the continue function, but the problems I've found are: it doesn't randomize colums, words and after second correct input I got "double free or corruption (prev)" crash. Do you know what could I do with these drawbacks?

Comment: Woops sorry, I moved that assignment before but program crashed and I forgot to fix that... Column's case is fixed now, 2 problems left.

Comment: Oh my, didn't realise it must be in loop as well...
Now it works like a charm, thank you again and have a good holidays! :)

Comment: Well you mean `fclose(fp);` after the `mvprintw(6, 1, "GAME OVER");` ? It returns me "Double free or corruption (top)" error. Also, moved `srand(time(NULL));` to main()

Comment: Ok, thanks a ton for all your help! Now I just need to add all of it to the graphic design of my program but it should be very easy :)